# System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable does not contain a definition for Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, list, ienumerable

I need to pass a list to a `IEnumerable` view but this error comes out:

> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable does not contain a definition for si_id and no extension method si_id accepting a first argument of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**View**

```
            @model IEnumerable<acgs_qm.Models.CreateStudent>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.si_id) //Error
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.si_id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_id)
            </div>


  <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.si_fname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.si_fname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.si_fname)
            </div>
   //etc
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RegisterStudent()
{
    Models.ModelActions action = new Models.ModelActions();
    var model = new acgs_qm.Models.CreateStudent
    {
        GradeLevel = action.getGrade(),
        Guardian = action.getGuardian(),
        si_id = action.getcode("student_info_tb", "si_id", "1")
    };
    List<CreateStudent> stud = new List<CreateStudent>();
    stud.Add(model);
    return View(stud);
}
```

I can't change  the `IEnumerable` because I'm passing the value of my post like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterStudent(CreateStudent Create, string submitbutton, string searchTerm)
{

    acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions Ma = new acgs_qm.Models.ModelActions();
    List<CreateStudent> stud = new List<CreateStudent>();

    switch (submitbutton)
    {
        case "search":
            stud = Ma.searchStud(searchTerm);

            return View(stud);
```

Comment: if you do model[0].si_id what happens?

Comment: You are pretending it is a single item, but actually it is a list.

Comment: @PatrickHofman how can i fix that sir?

Comment: You are creating a `List<CreateStudent>` and adding only 1 `CreateStudent` to it - why not just set the `CreateStudent` as the model  - `return View(model)` then `@model acgs_qm.Models.CreateStudent`. That will solve the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view is intended to create just a single student record, then pass in a single student, not a 'list of' with just one row.

Change your `@model` to:

```
@model acgs_qm.Models.CreateStudent
```

And your Controller action:

```
return View(model); // model is a single student record
```

Answer (score 1):

I you want to display all students in the list you must loop over it, e.g.

```
@model IEnumerable<acgs_qm.Models.CreateStudent>    
@foreach (var student in Model) {
        <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => student.si_id)
         </div>
         @* etc ... *@
    }
```